# How to get Basic Waypoint working (no-framework); Waypoint is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am using Waypoints, and am unable to get the Basic Waypoint working. I have two JS files: the reference to Waypoints, and the main JS file. When I check my console, I receive the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Waypoint is not defined."

HTML:

```
 <section id="waypoints">content</section>
```

Bottom of HTML File:

```
<script src="/js/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Main JS file contains:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('waypoints'),
  handler: function() {
   console.log('arrived at waypoints');
   notify('Basic waypoint triggered')
}
  offset: 20
})
```

Comment: Please provide code examples of what you have done so far.

Comment: My bad I submitted this before I added that information, will add it shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to have the entire Waypoints directory in my project, and not just the noframework file. When I reference the two JS files as listed in my question, the basic Waypoint works.

Answer (score 0):

You required one more js file inclusion in you code-

```
 waypoints.js
```

Comment: Thanks. I was following http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/, and chose to reference the no-framework version via the instruction: "Choose the one that fits your needs and include it." This is why I am referencing noframework.waypoints.min.js. Do I need to include waypoints.js on top of the noframework version?

Comment: noframework.waypoints.min.js and jQuery and Zepto are the framework on which waypoint is running.but for using the waypoints feature you must need to include waypoints.js